# Lost Touch detection for UiButton after tabbarcontroller hiding action

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm writing an app with a tabbarcontroller that holds some NavigationViewController. Each of This NavigationController holds some ViewControllers. Sometimes during navigation i need to hide the tabbar, the code i use:

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {


  for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, [self ScreenHeight], view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else
    {
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, [self ScreenHeight])];
    }

}


}
```

All works great until i try to add a button at the bottom of the screen. I can't touch a button placed in the bottom of the screen, tabbar is correctly hidden and the button is visible... If i move up the button it returns to works correctly...It seems like the tabbar never moves out of the screen... How i can do?

Comment: what [self AltezzaSchermo] will return

Comment: sorry, i have edited my question. It returns the height of the screen, 480 or 568...

Comment: its work for me try here https://www.dropbox.com/s/owzpykfa2ryxhet/demoTabbar.zip?dl=0

Comment: if you add button runtime then please add that code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ViewController* vC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
vC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

and make sure that button is at uppermost level. in your case bottom toolbar hiding button

Answer (score 0):

**i had done it with your code and it works perfect for me**
[download project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/owzpykfa2ryxhet/demoTabbar.zip?dl=0)

**Description**
Tab bar is hidden using code given by OP and

**Screen**
[image]

Comment: thanks , i have tried your code works for me too. Anyway there are many differences between this example and my app... Autolayout,the function is inserted in the app delegate , my in the viewcontroller directly... I think i can't take make a correct comparision between may app and the example. However thanks

Comment: @user31929 It will be great if i know what you doing to solve problem, can you share your work ?